# NonSQL: initialization of DB -object in browser console? DB -logic in the user-space?

Tags: jquery, database, initialization, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to move the logic to the very high-level from the db. Technically, I am looking for extremely lazy-evaluation of things. I feel some non-sql -db is for this purpose because it looks like the computation is expensive in non-sql db and hence tend to be moved to the userspace. So

> `"by which NonSQL db I can initialize the DB -object in the
>   user-space probably in things such as JavaScript/jQuery?"`

**TRIALS**

> **Trial 0:** MongoDB, not possible according to this  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025808/how-can-i-initialize-mongodb-object-db-in-a-browser-console).
>
> **Trial 1:** CouchDB, open.
>
> > jQcouch may work, more [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqcouch),
> >     but cannot find the source code. So how can I initialize the couchDB
> >     object to do something simple as `db.test.save('hello world')` in the
> >     Browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `jquery.couch.js` of Futon is well-documented [here](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.html). You can see source code after installation of CouchDB for example with Ubuntu just `$ sudo apt-get install couchdb`:

> `"http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"`.

Related question about CouchDB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975117/using-couchdbs-jquery-couch-js).